# How can I move/arrange all desktop windows? (i.e. "Show Windows Stacked"

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Is it possible in C# (using Win32 API, or whatever) to programmatically arrange all open application windows?

For example, in Windows 7 if you right-click the taskbar there is an option called "Show windows stacked" and "Show windows side-by-side".

That is exactly what I'm trying to replicate by code.

To explain even further, I want to iterate through all open applications, display the main window, and then arrange it on the desktop/monitor along with all other open application windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`TileWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633554.aspx). Some examples:

```
TileWindows(NULL, MDITILE_HORIZONTAL, NULL, 0, NULL); // "Show windows stacked"
TileWindows(NULL, MDITILE_VERTICAL, NULL, 0, NULL); // "Show windows side-by-side"
```

If you wanted to cascade the windows, you could use [`CascadeWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632674.aspx):

```
CascadeWindows(NULL, MDITILE_ZORDER, NULL, 0, NULL); // "Cascade windows"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it using windows API, take a look at this link, it explains how to use some of the functions, including the ones that let you enumerate all open windows

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shrijeetnair/win32api12062005005528AM/win32api.aspx

and here you have the function that lets you resize and move a window

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx