# Split the screen between applications in VBA

Tags: vba, winapi, screen

I'm working with my Excel files on two different monitor, 2560x1080 at work and 1920x1080 at home.

The file is used to open and manipulate Internet Explorer by using IE object and I want to split the screen in two and have IE window to the right, always 1000 pixels wide and Excel to the left, occupying the rest of the screen, regardless of the monitor I'm using.

How can I do that? I tried using this:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "user32" Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

With Application
    .WindowState = xlNormal
    .Left = 0
    .Top = 0
    .Height = (vidheight * 0.75) - 28
    .Width = (vidWidth - 1000) * 0.75
End With

Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
apiShowWindow IE.hwnd, 1

With IE
    .Left = (vidWidth - 1000) * 0.75
    .Top = 0
    .Height = (vidheight * 0.75) - 28
    .Width = 1000 * 0.75
End With
```

It doesn't work, not even the height of the windows is not the same, even though it has the same formula for both windows...

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a program to do this. You can tile the windows.

Comment: If you *do* want a program to do this, I'd recommend using the API to tile the windows.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15773260/4088852).

Comment: I don't want to tile the windows, I need to resize them during the execution of the macro.